# How to get a servlet to read values from a JSP and redirect to another JSP?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm new to JSP and web based programming in general and I have been trying to build a mock hotel booking page to work, basically it's a JSP file that displays the booking sheet with some text fields and radio buttons and such. When the user presses submit it should pass the data they entered into a servlet which checks the validity of the data e.g. whether all mandatory fields are filled in and whether the phone number is actually numbers etc. if all's well they should be redirected to another JSP that's like a final confirm screen. I can do all the input stuff and I can probably handle the validation stuff I just need to know how to get the first JSP to pass its data to the servlet and how to get the servlet to redirect to the second JSP.

Comment: I think you should take tutorials first before attempting to work on something Serious. You do not need to pass the values to a servlet to check whether they are entered. This validation can be performed at client end using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get the first JSP to pass its data to the servlet?

You can achieve this by simply creating a form.

```
<form action="YourServlet" method="post/get">
    <input type="text" name="phoneNumber">
    ...
    <!--other input fields-->
</form>
```

And to get the data from servlet you should implement the `doGet` or `doPost` method and write a code like

```
String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
//do some validations
```

> how to get the servlet to redirect to the second JSP.

And for your second question, after you successfully validated your data, you can redirect it to your second jsp by writing something like:

```
response.sendRedirect("YourSecondJsp.jsp");
```

Comment: all of your suggestions worked except for:     response.getRequestDispatcher();

Comment: @Jax, yes, I already changed it to `response.sendRedirect("YourSecondJsp.jsp");`